# Pull result only for missing data

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have a form where I display the result from DB, then you can add some of this data into DB. How to check/display only data that still not added into DB?

The way I pull results atm

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT oc_ekstri_frontend.*,
                                  oc_ekstri_image.id as img_id,
                                  oc_ekstri_image.name
                                  FROM oc_ekstri_image
LEFT JOIN oc_ekstri_frontend ON (oc_ekstri_frontend.id = oc_ekstri_image.frontend_id)
LEFT JOIN oc_ekstri_frontend_view ON (oc_ekstri_frontend_view.ekstri_id = oc_ekstri_image.id)
                                  WHERE oc_ekstri_frontend.subcat_id = '" . $id . "'");
```

Than you can add some of this data into oc_ekstri_frontend_view.
how to make the code like this?

```
AND WHERE oc_ekstri_image.id NOT EXIT IN oc_ekstri_frontend_view.ekstri_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using a `LEFT JOIN` with

```
oc_ekstri_frontend_view.ekstri_id = oc_ekstri_image.id
```

as your `JOIN` condition, if there is a case where the value of `oc_ekstri_image.id` doesn't exist in `oc_ekstri_frontend_view`, the value of `oc_ekstri_frontend_view.ekstri_id` will be `NULL`. So you can add:

```
AND oc_ekstri_frontend_view.ekstri_id IS NULL
```

to your `WHERE` condition to find those rows i.e.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT oc_ekstri_frontend.*,
                                  oc_ekstri_image.id as img_id,
                                  oc_ekstri_image.name
                                  FROM oc_ekstri_image
LEFT JOIN oc_ekstri_frontend ON (oc_ekstri_frontend.id = oc_ekstri_image.frontend_id)
LEFT JOIN oc_ekstri_frontend_view ON (oc_ekstri_frontend_view.ekstri_id = oc_ekstri_image.id)
                                  WHERE oc_ekstri_frontend.subcat_id = '" . $id . "'
                                    AND oc_ekstri_frontend_view.ekstri_id IS NULL");
```

Comment: i face another problem , actually i need to match and product_id from oc_ekstri_frontend_view.product_id = $product_id i tried to add another AND oc_ekstri_frontend_view.product_id = '" . $product_id . "' but do not work where is my mistake ?

Comment: @bobibobi You should ask another question - it would be easier if you could give the whole query in it.